# Редактирование строк в DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

в `DataFrame` нужно отобрать в колонке `Type2` значения "газ", затем по колонке `Type` отобрать значения "руб/1000м", и среди таких строк разделить значение `Price` на 1000. После всего этого, изменить значение в `Type` на "руб/м"
Провести такую же операцию для "вода" в `Type2`. И записать все это в исходный `DataFrame`.

Хочу получить что-то типо такого:

```
Kir4    руб/м   газ     2   6.5
```

[Исходник](https://dropmefiles.com/YVI9F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [288]: df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\book1.xlsx')

In [289]: df
Out[289]:
            Type Type2  Max   Price
Kir1       руб/м  вода    5     3.7
Kir2       руб/м  вода    4     4.2
Kir3   руб/1000м   газ    3  4600.0
Kir4   руб/1000м  газ     2  6500.0
Kir5       руб/м   газ    2     5.2
Kir6   руб/1000м  вода    3  6100.0
Kir7       руб/м   газ    2     4.0
Kir8       руб/м  вода    2     6.0
Kir9   руб/1000м   газ    5  9100.0
Kir10      руб/м  вода    4     7.0

In [290]: mask = (df['Type']=='руб/1000м') & (df['Type2'].str.contains('\s*газ\s*'))

In [291]: df.loc[mask, 'Price'] /= 1000

In [292]: df.loc[mask, 'Type'] = 'руб/м'

In [293]: df
Out[293]:
            Type Type2  Max   Price
Kir1       руб/м  вода    5     3.7
Kir2       руб/м  вода    4     4.2
Kir3       руб/м   газ    3     4.6
Kir4       руб/м  газ     2     6.5
Kir5       руб/м   газ    2     5.2
Kir6   руб/1000м  вода    3  6100.0
Kir7       руб/м   газ    2     4.0
Kir8       руб/м  вода    2     6.0
Kir9       руб/м   газ    5     9.1
Kir10      руб/м  вода    4     7.0
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [295]: df
Out[295]:
            Type      Type2  Max   Price
Kir1       руб/м       вода    5     3.7
Kir2       руб/м       вода    4     4.2
Kir3   руб/1000м        газ    3  4600.0
Kir4   руб/1000м       газ     2  6500.0
Kir5       руб/м        газ    2     5.2
Kir6   руб/1000м       вода    3  6100.0
Kir7       руб/м        газ    2     4.0
Kir8       руб/м       вода    2     6.0
Kir9   руб/1000м        газ    5  9100.0
Kir10      руб/м       вода    4     7.0
Kir11  руб/1000м       газ2    3  1111.0
Kir12  руб/1000м  газировка    3  2222.0

In [296]: mask = (df['Type']=='руб/1000м') & (df['Type2'].str.match('^\s*газ\s*$'))

In [297]: mask
Out[297]:
Kir1     False
Kir2     False
Kir3      True
Kir4      True
Kir5     False
Kir6     False
Kir7     False
Kir8     False
Kir9      True
Kir10    False
Kir11    False
Kir12    False
dtype: bool

In [298]: df.loc[mask, 'Price'] /= 1000

In [299]: df.loc[mask, 'Type'] = 'руб/м'

In [300]: df
Out[300]:
            Type      Type2  Max   Price
Kir1       руб/м       вода    5     3.7
Kir2       руб/м       вода    4     4.2
Kir3       руб/м        газ    3     4.6
Kir4       руб/м       газ     2     6.5
Kir5       руб/м        газ    2     5.2
Kir6   руб/1000м       вода    3  6100.0
Kir7       руб/м        газ    2     4.0
Kir8       руб/м       вода    2     6.0
Kir9       руб/м        газ    5     9.1
Kir10      руб/м       вода    4     7.0
Kir11  руб/1000м       газ2    3  1111.0
Kir12  руб/1000м  газировка    3  2222.0
```

Comment: Подскажите, что значит именно такая конструкция `str.contains('\s*газ\s*'))`, почему нельзя было писать `['Type2']=='газ'` ?

Comment: Плюс данная функция находит значения даже если `str.contains('\s*га\s*'))`. Т.е. , как я понял, функция ищет не полное соответствие, а то, что данные символы будут присутствовать, т.е. строку "газ2" или "газировка" он тоже распознает и изменит значение. А мне нужно именно точный отбор. Как это реализовать?

Comment: @Max, у вас в данных в некоторых строках есть пробелы в конце строки: `'газ '` - `str.contains('\s*газ\s*'))` - учитывает эту особенность (`'\s*газ\s*'` - это Regular Expression)

Comment: Ну это просто случайно так вышло, так как мне получить только уникальные значения? чтобы "газ" и "газ2" не опознавались как одинаковые под `'\s*газ\s*'`